# How to run commands in parallel in bash and load their output into variables?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have some expensive (slow) operations that could run in parallel

```
SERVERS=$(cmd1)
ROUTERS=$(cmd2)
NETWORKS=$(cmd3)
KEYPAIRS=$(cmd3)
```

I do want to speedup this by running these in parallel, but without using ugly hacks like redirecting their output to files and loading the files after their execution.

Is there a nice way to parallelize this in bash?

Answer (score 2):

One thought that comes to mind straight away is temp files.
So run your jobs in the background, redirect to a file, wait for the jobs to complete & read the files.

```
( job1 > /tmp/job1.out 2> /dev/null ; echo $? > /tmp/job1.ret ) &
( job2 > /tmp/job2.out 2> /dev/null ; echo $? > /tmp/job2.ret ) &
( job3 > /tmp/job3.out 2> /dev/null ; echo $? > /tmp/job3.ret ) &

wait

if [[ $(cat /tmp/job1.ret) -eq 0 ]] ; then job1_out=$(cat /tmp/job1.out) ; fi
if [[ $(cat /tmp/job2.ret) -eq 0 ]] ; then job2_out=$(cat /tmp/job2.out) ; fi
if [[ $(cat /tmp/job3.ret) -eq 0 ]] ; then job3_out=$(cat /tmp/job3.out) ; fi

# the rest
```

Comment: Yep but this created temp files, not the best experience. I am still searching for alternatives without temp files.

Answer (score 1):

I think [GNU parset](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parset.html) is what you are looking for. In your case it would look like this:

```
parset "SERVERS ROUTERS NETWORKS KEYPAIRS" :::: cmd1 cmd2 cmd3 cmd4
```

Comment: This may work but I am not willing to rely on tools that are from available by default on Linux or MacOS, as I want to keep the solution free of dependencies.